# Multiple Conditions for If-Else statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was just trying to imitate a simple login procedure,

how do I write multiple conditions for if-else statement?

e.g. if condition 1 **AND** condition 2 are correct, then....

I've tried using "**AND**", "**,**","**&**" and "**+**"....

```
val userID1 = "ABCD"
val userpass="1234567"

fun main() {

    println("Please insert user id :")
    val userIDread = readLine().toString()

    println("Please insert your password: ")
    val userpassread = readLine().toString()


    if (userIDread == userID1, userpassread == userpass){
        println("access granted")
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer after several more tries:

```
if (userIDread == userID1 && userpassread == userpass){
        println("access granted")
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's a good idea to check the language documentation for such basic functionality. Here are the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#booleans) for boolean operators.

> Built-in operations on booleans include:
>
> - `||` – disjunction (logical OR)
> - `&&` – conjunction (logical AND)
> - `!` - negation (logical NOT)
>
> `||` and `&&` work lazily.